# HorizontalScrollView with centered elements

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView that is filled dynamically with TextViews. Sometime there is one, two, three or more elements. What I'm looking for is a way to have the items centered regardless of the numbers of elements.

For example, With one element:

```
| --------- MenuA --------- |
```

With two elements:

```
| ---- MenuA --- MenuB ---- |
```

With three elements:

```
| - MenuA - MenuB - MenuC - |
```

With five elements (MenuD and MenuE are hidden):

```
| MenuA - MenuB - MenuC - Me|
```

---

Update: Here is a simple layout with two menus. How do I center MenuA and MenuB?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:text="MenuA" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="MenuB" android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So your `ScollView` is horizontal (wider than the screen), the items are screen-centered?

Comment: Yes, my HorizontalScrollView is horizontal, and the items should be centered horizontally

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use the gravity attribute :

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
EDIT : 03.30 :

I found it ! only had to set the gravity to the upper LinearLayout : all you need to do is add a little padding/margins to make the textviews more comfortable to read !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuB" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuB" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuB" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuB" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuA" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MenuB" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

keep me posted !

Comment: I tried settings android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" and the TextViews are still located on the right

Comment: could you please send your full layout ?

Comment: It should actually just be `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, , since `layout_gravity` will just place the HorizontalScrollView at the parent's horizontal center, but offhand, I'm not quite sure even that will work as you're expecting..

Comment: Worked for me after a small tweak. My layout contained a `LinearLayout` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`, I had to wrap the two of them in a new `LinearLayout` purely to assign the orientation and gravity to this.